# Alignment issue with bullet and text wrap with InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, text-wrap

[Post was reedited to show the actual constraints, the solution provided for a simplified version was not working properly...]

I have a little issue with an InDesign document.

Here is an example:
[image]
[image]

The block is filled with a right-aligned text with bullets (set right in the bullet styles). Both bullet styles and paragraph styles are set with a 30 mm left indent.

How can the bullet be right-aligned and/or respect the 30 mm left indent ?

(The easiest solution would be to narrow the paragraph block, but I can't do that as it would affect the paragrah underline)

Comment: I think you need to include a sample image.

Comment: I guess you're right :) Here it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is indeed quite simple.
No left-offset nor text-wrap are required.

The text block should be smaller to fit the actual text area dimensions, without any offsets. Then, the paragraph rule can overflow the text block if set with a negative left offset.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

<strike>It sounds like you're wanting the bullets/text left aligned, but on the right side of a text box.</strike>

<strike>My suggestion based on that assumption is: Have you tried doing left align, but increase the left indent so all the text gets pushed to the right side?</strike>

EDIT: My original suggestion above was based on assumptions that weren't what the original asker was needing. After seeing their example I understand it better (hopefully!).

### Option 1:

I believe Mark Sturgess' suggestion will do what you desire. Here is a visual representation of that below:

[image: Align right text with bullets and a box with text-wrap applied]

### Option 2a (Manual Input):

Keep *Text Wrap* enabled for the background box and use [Alt codes](http://www.alt-codes.net/bullet_alt_codes.php) to manually add bullets (e.g.: "•" ). According to the link above, it's Alt+7 or Alt+0149 on a numeric keypad for a PC. If you're on a Mac, it's Option+8 (the 8 key at top of keyboard).

### Option 2b (Manual Input):

Use [Glyphs](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/502084) (link is about Illustrator, but the principle is the same). Menu item: `Type > Glyphs`. You can copy and paste it repeatedly where needed in your document.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than a true answer to me

Comment: You're right, It probably wasn't a true answer. My reputation is low due to recently registering for this portion of StackExchange. I can't make direct comments to the asker (need at least 50 rep). I needed more information, but I tried to answer to the best of my ability with the information at hand. I hope my edit to my answer is more of a solution :)

Comment: Your solution works well, but it's important to underline the importance of the left indent. Ignoring text wrap actually puts the bullet over the block. Therefore, a left indent is required, for the same width as the block's. Also, I can't use the options 2 as I use numeric bullets (but I didn't tell to simplify..). Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clicking your 'first block' then hit object > text frame options > then check the 'ignore text wrap' box, that should sort it...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I need the text to be wrapped. If not, it would be covered by the second block...

Comment: can you upload a screenshot?